# Creating Zip Code-Level Choropleth Using Leaflet.JS?

Tags: leaflet, zip-codes, choropleth

I am new to Leaflet.js.

Is it possible to create a choropleth using zip-code level data?

I've seen plenty of choropleth examples using state-level data and even a few using county-level data.

If so, what would be a good way to go about it using Leaflet?

Do I need to obtain coordinates for the shapes of each zip code I'm interested in visualizing?

Comment: You can find ZCTA (the US Census Bureau's approximation of zipcodes, an explanation of which you can read about [here](http://gis.washington.edu/phurvitz/zip_or_zcta/)) shapefiles here: ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/ZCTA5/tl_2013_us_zcta510.zip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Get a polygon feature class of the zip codes that you want to add
2. Store your polygon zip code feature class in a RDBMS like PostGIS
3. [Encode](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60310/how-to-add-a-polygon-from-postgis-st-asgeojson-into-leaflet) your polygon zip code geometry objects to GeoJSON objects
4. [Create a GeoJSON layer](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) and populate it with your GeoJSON objects
5. Use the polygon extension of the [path abstract class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path) from Leaflet documentation to symbolize fill color, opacity etc. based on data either supplied by user or from your polygon feature class.

Answer (score 4):

Check out a tutorial I wrote on my blog:

http://dillonshook.com/leaflet-zip-code-map-part-1/

Doing this dynamically requires some back-end setup to serve up the geoJSON with data joined